# Weird syntaxerror at insert-function using npgsql

Tags: .net, postgresql, plpgsql, npgsql

I have a function which does simply inserts some values into a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION register_new_user(
   pnick character varying
 , ppasshash character varying
 , pmail character varying
 )
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
Declare
Begin
Insert into registration
values(pNick, pPasshash, pMail);
End;
$BODY$   LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now when I use this function in pgAdmin like

```
Select register_new_user('a','b','c') as Answer;
```

It works just fine, but when i try to do it via my .NET-Databasemanagement I get a syntax error from npgsql at $2 (that is what the exception says).

This is how I call the function via VB.NET:

```
Using func As DatabaseFunction = DatabaseFunction.CreateNewFunctionInstance("register_new_user")
    func.AddParameter("pnick", txt_Nick.Text, Data.ParameterDirection.Input)
    func.AddParameter("ppasshash", passhash, Data.ParameterDirection.Input)
    func.AddParameter("pmail", txt_Mail.Text, Data.ParameterDirection.Input)
    func.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

In the case of passhash it doesn't care WHAT i write in there, even "hello" doesn't work. I use UTF8-Encoding for the passhash and say that in the connectionstring too. My databasemanagement for my .NET-Programms looks like this:

```
Public Class DatabaseFunction
            Implements IDisposable
            Public dbcon As IDbConnection
            Private comm As NpgsqlCommand
            Public trans As IDbTransaction
            Private funcname As String = String.Empty
            Private dr As IDataReader = Nothing
            Public Sub New(ByVal functionname As String, ByVal Connection As IDbConnection, ByVal Transaction As IDbTransaction)
                Try
                    dbcon = Connection
                    trans = Transaction
                    funcname = functionname
                    comm = New NpgsqlCommand(functionname, dbcon, trans)
                    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw New Exception("Fehler bei der Initierung einer Datenbankfunktion: " & ex.Message)
                End Try
            End Sub

            Public Shared Function CreateNewFunctionInstance(ByVal FunctionName As String) As DatabaseFunction
                Try
                    Dim dbcon As IDbConnection = DatabaseConnection.CreateNewOpenConnection()
                    Return New DatabaseFunction(FunctionName, dbcon, dbcon.BeginTransaction)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw ex
                End Try
            End Function

            Public Sub AddParameter(ByVal Name As String, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal Direction As ParameterDirection)
                Try
                    Dim newparam As NpgsqlParameter = comm.CreateParameter()
                    newparam.ParameterName = Name
                    newparam.Value = parameter
                    newparam.Direction = Direction
                    comm.Parameters.Add(newparam)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw ex
                End Try
            End Sub

            Public Function ExecuteReader() As IDataReader
                Try
                    comm.Connection = dbcon
                    comm.Transaction = trans
                    comm.Prepare()
                    dr = DirectCast(comm.ExecuteReader(), IDataReader)
                    Return dr
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw ex
                End Try
            End Function

            Public Sub ExecuteNonQuery()
                Try
                    comm.Connection = dbcon
                    comm.Transaction = trans
                    comm.Prepare()
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw ex
                End Try
            End Sub

            Public Shared Function CreateNewDatabaseConnection() As IDbConnection
                Try
                    Return DatabaseConnection.CreateNewOpenConnection()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw ex
                End Try
            End Function

            Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
                Try
                    If Not dr Is Nothing Then
                        If Not dr.IsClosed Then
                            dr.Close()
                            dr.Dispose()
                        End If
                    End If
                    trans.Commit()
                    comm.Dispose()
                    dbcon.Close()
                    dbcon.Dispose()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw ex
                End Try
            End Sub
        End Class
```

Can someone help me please to fix this issue cause it is driving me nuts here.

---

I recently found out that the Syntaxerror is caused by the command.prepare()-Sub. when i execute my stuff directly it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Can it be that you pass a number `1234` instead of a text `'1234'` (with single quotes) here:

```
...
func.AddParameter("ppasshash", passhash, Data.ParameterDirection.Input)
...
```

If that does nor solve your problem, a look at the database log will. With standard configuration you will find a more verbose error message including the statement that was actually sent to the database.
PostgreSQL has a lot more to say in such a case than just:

```
syntax error at $2
```

Look for `log_destination` in your `postgresql.conf` file. Logging is defined there.
[More about where to log in the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHERE)

---

You may want to simplify / improve your PostgreSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION register_new_user(
  _pnick text
 ,_ppasshash text
 ,_pmail text
 )
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
INSERT INTO registration (pnick, ppasshash, pmail) -- assuming these col names
VALUES($1, $2, $3);
$BODY$   LANGUAGE sql;
```

- There is no need for PL/pgSQL here (while it is certainly possible), a plain SQL function does the trick. (You have to use numbered parameters ($1, $2, ..) in the function body of SQL functions, though)
- *Always* use a target list for `INSERT` in functions.
  Else, if the underlying table changes it will break in unexpected ways.
- Avoid naming conflicts by making your parameter names unique. I like to use a `_` prefix for that, but that is my arbitrary choice.

Comment: your numberguess wasn't the solve to this puzzle. can you tell me where to find those logs? i'm pretty new to postgre...

Comment: @Husky110: I added a bit to my answer.

Comment: thanks for your time, but the problem is, that the function itself works perfect. it seems to me that the problem is located somewhere inside the programcode, because when i run it from an editor it works perfect. i am aware of the problem with the insert-targetlist and i use the p as prefix to avoid collisions between variables and collumns.

Comment: the syntaxerror is thrown by npgsql, not the database itself. (so it seems to me)

Comment: @Husky110: I had another look, but I am no expert with .net and npgsql. Sorry.